# MVC5 and Entity Framework Multi Threading

Tags: multithreading, entity-framework, caching, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an application written with MVC5 and Entity Framework 6.
When the user logins to the home page, I run a query and get the summary of the reports available to view.

It seems in certain situation when multiple users are logged in for different clients, one user got the data of another client instead of theirs. 
The admin staff logged it at that time too to verify and they confirmed that it's happening. But by the time I was notified, It was not happening again, it was late and not many users working.

My home controller is using DI to get the DB context.

```
 private IDataRepository db = null;
 public HomeController(IDataRepository dbContext)
 {
     this.db = dbContext;
 }
```

I am using Ninject for dependency injection

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private IKernel kernel;
    public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernelParam)
    {
        kernel = kernelParam;
        AddBindings();
    }
    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
    }
    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
    }
    private void AddBindings()
    {
        kernel.Bind<IDataRepository>().To<DataRepository>();

    }
}
```

The repository and dbcontext are defined in a separate library project

This is the code to call the summary from the home controller

```
   var summaries = db.reportSummary(client_id, 0, fromDate, toDate, 0, 10); 
    foreach (sp_slct__report_Result s in summaries)
    {
        reports.Add(new ClientReportSummary(s));
    }
```

the method ReportSummary is in a separate class like this:

```
  public class ClientReportSummary
    {
        sp_slct_report_Result summary = null;

        public ClientReportSummary(sp_slct_report_Result summary)
        {
            this.summary = summary;
        }
   }
```

And the DbContext Function

```
public IEnumerable<sp_slct__report_Result> reportSummary(int clientId, 
   long reportId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, byte minStatus, 
   byte maxStatus)
{
    try
    {
        return sp_slct__report(clientId, reportId, startDate, endDate, 
             minStatus, maxStatus);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.error(ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

The sp_slct__report_Result is a stored procedure.

I don't think that the DI is not thread safe, but maybe that Entity Framework is caching the data and/or query and returning the wrong thing?

I am not even sure how to test this, is there any way to track back and see what queries were executed at a certain time ?

Any recommendations to prevent/debug this, best practices, would AsNoTracking() fix this ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have multithreading in the title and tagged. I hope you have not tried to manage multiple threads in your asp.net app.

Comment: no, I am not doing multithreading. What I meant is that if multiple users access the application and same controller at the same time, would those calls be thread safe in terms of entity framework

Comment: Within a single context they are not thread safe. You should not share an EF context between requests.

Comment: I am injecting it in the controller, it should be a new instance for each request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have some logging configured. You could log your raw queries by configuring the log action of the Database property

```
context.Database.Log = s => Logger.info(s);
```

This will work for stored procedures mapped into an EF model.